# why cannot i import enum to my angular2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums

I have this enum under the folders: `country-details/enum`

```
export enum ConfigTypes {
  STAFF, PROD
}
```

and I try to import it to another component, though I get a `cannot resolve symbol` error

even though my component is in the root folder which contains `country-details` folder

```
import {ConfigTypes} from "country-details/enum";
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path should be "./country-details/enum"

> import {ConfigTypes} from "./country-details/enum";

Comment: my component is in the root folder which contains country-details folder

Comment: but you need to add './' in the begining